# xpages on click event from view panel column - pop up dialog forms from views

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

There are 2 datasources: `Cdoc` ( the doc. content ) and the `Pdoc` ( inside a dialog ).

These 2 datasources are linked together based on the `Cdoc'UNID`.

My main view panel is like this:

```
     [_A_common_field] from Cdoc1 and all Pdocs from Cdoc1 ( this column is categorized )   
        Cdoc1
        Pdoc 1 from Cdoc1
        Pdoc 2 from Cdoc1
     [_A_common_field] from Cdoc2 and all Pdocs from Cdoc2 ( this column is categorized )
        Cdoc2
        Pdoc 1 from Cdoc2
```

How can I compute the target property from my `viewPanel1` considering the fact that I want `Pdoc` to be opened in the dialog ( as it was created ) and `Cdoc` to be opened in the 'clasical' mode as it was when the `target` property wasn't added ?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to refer to the datasources name . The 'pseudocode' wish I want to implement is something like this: if datasource is Cdoc then _target = ???

else _target = showing the dialog . Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can check the form name of the document

Comment: Real code rocks! You might want to use "use XPages associated with the form" or use a inline form which is more compatible with mobile device

Comment: A view has ONE data source

Comment: In my question I refer to my document data sources ( which are 2 ) and the docs. are listing by the view panel. Thanks

Comment: My approach: make a CSJS function "open" to redirect to URL (for Cdoc) or popup/dialog (for Pdoc) according to param. The view will then contain call like: open("{#row.id}", "{#rov.form}")

Comment: MFGFLay, regarding your last comment, you can only show a view datasource in a view panel, your document data sources are therefore (just about) irrelevant in the computation.  If you cannot use the "use XPages associated with the form" as mentioned by stwissel, the the approach mentioned by Frantisek is the best option.  Just be sure that those columns exist in the view.  I personally would compute what to do based on the form names.  The main question is, why is "xpage associated with the form" not good enough?  are you opening this document in the dialog?

Comment: @Greg I'm trying to develop Frantisek suggestion, as it is what I expected and what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: @MFG Flay: I agree with the Franstisek Kassuth's solution, that's the best way to go around. Use CSJS to handle the PDOC and CDOC onclick events. However, I again repeat myself, its better to use repeat control here(if its not a major change for you just go for it). I have faced this problem before and even after you solve it; it would not give you a full control, whereas on the other hand repeat control gives full flexibility..

Comment: @ChintanParekh could you give me an example? I'm newbie in xpages development, been a Lotus Notes developer, and i Don't understand really well.

Comment: Ya, sure, I will try to message you by the end of the day :)

Comment: @ChintanParekh Hope you didn't forget me ... Could you give me a simple example then? Thanks. You could post it as an answer as I already started a bounty

Comment: I am so so sorry. Will definitely do it in few hours..sorry again. .!!

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth could you give me a little example using your example for the view call: open{"{#row.id}","{#rov.form}"} ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are trying to open up the selected document from the view panel in the dialog.  (In essence, open a dialog with the values from document listed in an embedded view)

**forward**
More than likely I would just open the document in another window and be done with it.  But if you want to open this in a dialog, fine.  If you define the data source in the dialog itself, be warned that I personally have had issues with such approaches in the past and I think that the datasources should be defined in the xpage view level.

**answer**
1. Do not allow any links in the view.
2. Have a checkbox available in the view.
3. Add a button where you will get the NoteID of the selected document, also making sure that a document was selected.

```
var vwpnl = getComponent("homeViewPanel");
        var docIDArray = vwpnl.getSelectedIds();
        if(docIDArray.length != 1){
            view.postScript("alert('"+MessageController.getMessageForCurrentUser("msg_SelectOneDocument") +"')");
            return;
        }
        var firstID = docIDArray.length > 0 ? docIDArray[0] : "";
        return firstID;
```

(you can ignore the MessageController as that is one of my helper classes for language specific user messages.)

4 use that noteID (whether in viewScope or not) in the calculation of the data source in the dialog making certain that dialog has the correct settings, like refreshing etc.

**EDIT**

The good part about keeping this approach (performance aside) in your toolbox is that once you get a handle on the document itself, you can compute anything.  using the noteID just to set a dialog property is just one example.  You could create a document object and use the values to do anything you want, including opening another page, other actions, basically whatever you want. It might not be the best option for your current use case (you did not really specify your use case), but for future readers it will hopefully be a help.

Comment: I'm not trying to open all the documents in dialog, only certain documents: where the doc datasource is Pdoc. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the view panel target function. Try with a dataView (xe:dataview) where:
`[_A_common_field]` is for `categorieColumn`

`Cdoc1` is for `summaryColumn` and the System will create the OpenLink for Cdoc

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView2" columnTitles="true"
    pageName="/Cdoc_Write.xsp" rowStyleClass="xspHtmlTrView"
    openDocAsReadonly="true" collapsibleDetail="true"
    collapsibleRows="true" var="viewEntry">...
```

Then create a new customControl (CC) and paste it into Details section.

Into the CC you need a table with 3 Columns and a Repeat-Control. With xe:repeat you will create the PDoc's into a tr like this:

```
    <xp:table>

            <xp:repeat rows="30" id="repeatResults" var="resultDoc"
                repeatControls="false" first="0" indexVar="indexResults">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (viewEntry.isDocument()){
        var strUniqueID = viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("Cdoc'UNID");    
        if(null != strUniqueID & ""!=strUniqueID) {
            var  teamsView = database.getView("All_PDocs4Cdoc");
            return  teamsView.getAllDocumentsByKey(strUniqueID);
            }
        }}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:tr>
                       <xp:td >Pdoc[j] from Cdoc[i]</xp:td>
                       <xp:td > modal or tooltip dialog link</xp:td>
                       <xp:td > Dialog - Form</p:td>
                </xp:tr>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:table>
```

The 2nd column ist for the  link to open the PDoc into a Dialog -> see XPages Extension Library Demo / in Context Dialog.

The 3rd. td contain the hide dialog form for Pdoc.

BTW the 1st. td contains Values from Pdoc[j] e.g. Subject

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understand from your question, this is what I will do, please correct me if I am wrong or missing anything here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="dominoView" viewName="ADR2"
            search="#{javascript:param.searchValue}" dataCache="full">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
<xp:table id="viewPanela" styleClass="xspRepeatTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:98%">
<xp:tr styleClass="xspHeaderRow">
        <xp:td style="width:2%"></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:label value="Title" id="label1"></xp:label></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:label value="Abteilung" id="label3"></xp:label></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
    <xp:repeat id="repeatList" value="#{javascript:dominoView}"
        var="ordnerData" rows="10" indexVar="repeatIndex">
        <xp:tr id="tr1">
            <xp:td><xp:image id="image1" style="width:12px" url="#{javascript:return findImage(ordnerData.getColumnValue('aIcon'));}"></xp:image></xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:div id="div1">
                    <xp:this.style>
                        <![CDATA[#{javascript:var level = ordnerData.getIndentLevel(); 
                            if(level != null && level > 0){
                                    return "padding-left:" + (level * 10) + "px !important";
                            }else{
                                    return "";
                            }}]]>
                    </xp:this.style>
                    <xp:link id="link1">
                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:ordnerData.getChildCount() > 0}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewPanela" immediate="true">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:ordnerData.toggleExpanded()}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                        <xp:image id="image5" alt="Toggle Row">
                            <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(ordnerData.isExpanded()){
                                            return("/tree_minus.gif");
                                        }else{
                                            return("/tree_plus.gif");
                                        }}]]></xp:this.url>
                        </xp:image>
                    </xp:link>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "  " +ordnerData.getColumnValue('$92')}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:div>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4" value="#{javascript:ordnerData.getColumnValue('$95')}"></xp:text></xp:td>
            <xp:eventHandler event="ondblclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var docid="#{javascript:ordnerData.getDocument().getUniversalID()}";
var link="";
var typ="#{javascript:ordnerData.getDocument().getItemValueString('aTyp')}";
link='xx_openPageN.xsp?aTyp='+typ+'&action=openDocument&documentId='+docid;
window.open(link,'New','width=1000, height=650, left=250px, top=250px, menubar=no, resizable=0, scrollbars=yes');
]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
<xp:tr styleClass="xspPagerRow">
        <xp:td colspan="4" align="right" style="width:100%">
            <xp:pager xp:key="headerPager" for="repeatList"
                id="pagerTop" partialRefresh="true"
                style="font-weight:inherit;margin-right:0.0px"
                layout="SeparatorPage Status FirstArrow Separator PreviousArrow Separator SeparatorPage Group Separator NextArrow Separator LastArrow">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:td>
</xp:tr>
</xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

**Explanation**

I have a simple dominoView as a viewSource which in your case would be a categorized view with Cdoc and Pdoc as response document. To determine the current clicked document , there is a simple javascript you can use:

```
if(level != null && level > 0)
    return "Is a PDoc with document id "+ordnerData.getDocument().getUniversalID();
else
    return "Is a CDoc with document id "+ordnerData.getDocument().getUniversalID();
```

Now, this allows you to perform different computation on different document. If you see my example, I just open a new window with the respective document in edit mode. You can have conditions based on your requirement here (eg. PDoc in a dialog and CDoc in a window). Please let me know if anything is not clear or missing. Sorry for being late on this. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Pdoc is not a response document to Cdoc. Also, Pdoc was created inside a dialog this is the reason I want all docs. Pdoc to be opened in the dialog. Cdoc i would like to be opened in the classical way: in the same window, not in a new window. I'm not using repeated controls, only a view panel.

Comment: You mentioned that the view is categorized based on a common field in Cdoc and Pdoc. So, it is a categorized view with Cdoc as parent document right?

Comment: Also, for opening in a dialog, I won't recommend to use a datasource. Instead, just get the field values based on the passed document id and save it the same way (please let me know if you need further description on this).

Comment: I thing it is my fault, I don't understand very well. So, Cdoc and Pdoc are two datasources binded to 2 forms: each form is a Document type, not a Response Doc. type.

Comment: Well, the dialog ( Pdoc ) is containing just a few fields which are in common with Cdoc. Also, there are several fields from Pdoc which I want to display in some embedded views.

Comment: I will try to use your example, but I don't think it will help me. Thanks a lot, anyway. I will notice you if I will make it works.

Comment: Yup, let me know..one more suggestion, just open a simple dialog and calculate all the fields based on the passed documentId. Hope it helps.

Comment: I will documenting regarding the view call open("{#row.id}", "{#rov.form}")  that Frantisek suggests to use.