# xpages computed onClick open forms

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying and trying for some time to resolve a `viewPanel` functionality - `var` property set to `rowData`.

Depending on the form name, I want to open the docs. ( which are listed in my `viewPanel` ) in a normal way and into a `<xe:dialog>` control. I did found this question [Xpages Dynamic dojo dialog control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690108/xpages-dynamic-dojo-dialog-control) and I'm trying to make it works in my case. the docs which I want to be open in the `<xe:dialog>`, are also created inside the dialog. By this viewpanel, I want to show/open them using this viewPanel control.

Here is the code from the `onClick` column event:

```
var formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");
var docUNID = rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID();
var href = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
var pe:NotesViewEntry = rowData

if ( formName == "fmCompanie") // in this case, it works OK.

{ href + "/doc.xsp?documentId=" + docUNID + "&action=openDocument"; }

else if ( formName == "fmPersContact" ) // hmm... Still trying...

{ viewScope.put("dlgDocUnid", pe.getUniversalID())
getComponent("exampleDialog").show(); }
```

So, by this event I'm trying to set a `viewScope` variable which uses the UNID for the datasource in my `exampleDialog` control.

Also: the dialog control ( which lays on the same custom control as the viewPanel) has the `documentId`:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="Pdoc" formName="fmPersContact"
        ignoreRequestParams="true" scope="request">

        <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("dlgDocUnid");}]]></xp:this.documentId>
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Still, when I'm trying to open a doc. ( using `form == "fmPersContact"`) the dialog has all fields empty, even if the doc. is already fill with some field values.

I appreciate your help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are partially refreshing a component called "viewContent". Do you have a component with this name?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten yep. I corrected the partial refresh. I will update my question, now the dialog it's showing, but is like a 'newNote()', the fields are empty.

Comment: Can you also post the data component that you have used within the dialog? For instance, if you don't use action="editDocument", just documentId would not be enough to show the data. You might also put a computed field into the dialog to test if it passes the value correctly.

Comment: @SerdarBasegmez thanks for your response. I will update my question with the data component of the dialog.

Comment: Dialogs are not native to web applications. So you might be trying a solution for a problem you shouldn't have. The inline edit form and a repeat control might be a better choice

Comment: @SerdarBasegmez I just added action="editDocument" to my data component for the dialog, and it seems it works: the respective docs. are opened inside the dialog , and the dialog is showing the data correctly. Could you post this observation as an answer? I will make more tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data source in the dialog does not contain `action` attribute. Therefore it does not respect the `documentId` parameter and creating a new document within the dialog.

Add `action="editDocument"` attribute and it will work.

Also, check what you are refreshing with the `onclick` event. You should partially refresh an area that contains your data (e.g. dialog or the panel in your dialog, etc.)